# how to map two list values in class object using xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

i have two list of elements with same length eg.

```
List 1: profile1, profile2,profile3

List 2: 1,0,1
```

these lists are the public property in class objects.
i.e:

```
class Serviceinfo
{
[xmlArray("Profiles")]
[xmlArrayItem("Profile")]
public list<string> Profiles;
public list<int> state;

}
```

here i need to map each profile with its state. eg.

```
<serviceinfo>
 <profiles>
     <profile>profile1</profile>
     <state>1</state>
 </profiles>
<profiles>
      <profile>profile2</profile>
     <state>0</state>
 </profiles>
<profiles>
      <profile>profile3</profile>
     <state>1</state>
 </profiles>
</serviceinfo>
```

how do i change my class object, to return the above xml result. is it possible to get the above output in xml serialization method.

Comment: Don't torture yourself.Just define a Profile class and add two additinal properties, Profile and State

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done using `XmlSerializer` because your desired XML structure is quite strange when compared with your class.

But it definitely can be done using LINQ to XML:

```
var serviceInfo = new Serviceinfo { Profiles = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" }, state = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4 } };

var xml = new XDocument(
            new XElement("serviceinfo",
                serviceInfo.Profiles
                           .Zip(serviceInfo.state, (p, s) => new { p, s })
                           .Select(x =>
                               new XElement("profiles",
                                   new XElement("profile", x.p),
                                   new XElement("state", x.s.ToString())))));
```

If you really want to XML Serialization you should change your class structure to

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "serviceInfo")]
public class Serviceinfo
{
    [XmlElement("profiles")]
    public List<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "profile")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "state")]
    public int State { get; set; }
}
```

and use `XmlSerializer`:

```
var serviceInfo = new Serviceinfo
{
    Profiles = new List<Profile>() {
        new Profile { Name = "one", State = 1 },
        new Profile { Name = "two", State = 2 }
    }
};

var writer = new StringWriter();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Serviceinfo));

serializer.Serialize(writer, serviceInfo);

var xml = writer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gomathipriya : As per what I understand from your problem, the best solution would be create one single collection with both the values as properties as mentioned in the below example and then convert the entire collection to XML.

convert the Collection to XML : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=428

Sample C# Code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> Profiles = new List<string>();
        List<int> state = new List<int>();

        // Just filling the entities as per your needs
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Profiles.Add("P-" + i.ToString());
            state.Add(i);
        }

        listOfProfileState ProfileStateColl = new listOfProfileState();
        for (int i = 0; i < Profiles.Count; i++)
        {
            ProfileStateColl.Add(new ProfileState() { Profile = Profiles[i], State = state[i] });
        }
    }
}

public class ProfileState
{
    public string Profile { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
}

public class listOfProfileState : List<ProfileState>
{

}
```

as per the above mentioned example if you convert the collection 'ProfileStateColl' to XML you will have your solution that you need. :)